# Fait-on la différence entre les adjectifs démonstratifs masculins et féminin ?

Tags: pluriel, genre, démonstratifs, déterminants

Fait-on la différence entre les adjectifs démonstratifs masculins et féminins et entre les adjectifs singulier et pluriel ? Pouvez-vous donner des exemples ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oui, les adjectifs démonstratifs (ou *pronoms démonstratifs*) s'accordent en genre ou en nombre avec le nom qu'ils qualifient,

- **Singulier**

- **Masculin** *Cet* (devant une voyelle ou un *h* muet), *ce* (devant une consonne)¹

  > J'ai vu *cet* homme hier
  >   J'ai vu *cet* imbécile hier
  >   J'ai vu *ce* bonhomme hier
- **Féminin** *Cette*

  > J'ai vu *cette* femme hier

**Pluriel**

- **Masculin et féminin** *Ces*

> J'ai vu *ces* enfants hier

---

¹ C'est en fait un peu plus compliqué : pour *ou*, *u* et *y*, s'ils sont prononcés comme des semi-voyelles — donc essentiellement quand ils sont suivis d'une voyelle — on utilisera *ce*

> J'ai vu *ce* ouistiti hier
>   J'ai vu *ce* Uyghur hier
>   J'ai vu *ce* yack hier

mais s'ils sont prononcés comme des voyelles on utilisera bien *cet*.

> J'ai vu *cet* Ougrien hier
>   J'ai vu *cet* ulcère hier
>   J'ai vu *cet* ylang-ylang hier

Comment: J'ai vu sept femmes hier.